# Text file to JSON

Tags: text-processing, json, jq

I have a text file of `IP:PORT`, like for example

```
1.1.1.1:1919
2.2.2.2:111
1.1.1.1:987
```

I need to use them in a script which has a JSON format:

```py
async def main(loop):
    servers = [{
        "address": "ip",
        "port": port
    }, {
        "address": "ip",
        "port": port
    }]
```

I need to output as

```py
async def main(loop):
    servers = [{
        "address": "1.1.1.1",
        "port": 1919
    }, {
        "address": "2.2.2.2,
        "port": 111
    }, {
        "address": "1.1.1.1,
        "port": 987
    }]
```

I am using Linux.

Comment: Just for fun. oo contains the data: `pf="";printf "async def main(loop):\n\tservers = [";while IFS=":" read di dp; do printf "$pf {\n\t\t\"address\": \"$di\",\n\t\t\"port\": $dp\n\t}";pf=",";done <oo;printf "]\n"`

Comment: `async def`? Is that python? Then it is *not* JSON

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```bash
jq -nRr '
    [ inputs | split(":") | {address: first, port: last} ]
    | "async def main(loop):\n    servers = \(.)"
' addresses
```

outputs

```
async def main(loop):
    servers = [{"address":"1.1.1.1","port":"1919"},{"address":"2.2.2.2","port":"111"},{"address":"1.1.1.1","port":"987"}]
```

Comment: Neat. I would write the first part of that expression using `map()`: `[inputs] | map(split(":") | { address: first, port: last })`, but that's just personal preference.

Comment: Oh, you probably want `(last|tonumber)` to convert the port numbers from strings.

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
raku -MJSON::Fast -e 'my @a.=push(.split: ":") for lines; say to-json( ( %("address", .[0], "port", .[1].Int) for @a), :sorted-keys );'
```

Sample Input:

```
1.1.1.1:1919
2.2.2.2:111
1.1.1.1:987
```

Sample Output:

```json
    [
      {
        "address" : "1.1.1.1",
        "port" : 1919
      },
      {
        "address" : "1.1.1.1",
        "port" : 987
      },
      {
        "address" : "2.2.2.2",
        "port" : 111
      }
    ]
```

Note: Non-pretty-printed output can be obtained by setting `pretty => False`:

```json
~$ raku -MJSON::Fast -e 'my @a.=push(.split: ":") for lines; say to-json( ( %("address", .[0], "port", .[1].Int) for @a), pretty => False );'  file
[{"address":"1.1.1.1","port":1919},{"port":111,"address":"2.2.2.2"},{"port":987,"address":"1.1.1.1"}]
```

Other relevant modules in the Raku ecosystem include `JSON::Tiny`, `JSON::Pretty`, and `JSON::Pretty::Sorted`.

https://raku.land/cpan:TIMOTIMO/JSON::Fast
https://raku.org